# Shadow Copies are not being taken for all subfolders

Tags: windows-server-2012, vss

I enabled Shadow Copies on a whole drive that holds user folder shares.  As per the best practices, I re-directed the Shadow Volume to a different drive.  Both are VHDs running on the same server, but that shouldn't prevent copies from being taken.

What is happening is, d:\share1 does not have any previous versions, but d:\share2 does.  Even if I force a non-scheduled backup, share1 does not have anything listed in previous versions.

Furthermore, and to my dismay, d:\share2\user1 is backed up, but user2 is not, and within the user folders, it seems random as to which folders get backed up, and which don't.

Now, it's only been a few days since I enabled shadow copies, but I thought that if I forced a manual backup, it would get everything.

This is Server 2012, Running Hyper-V, and the VM (again 2012) has 3 drives, one boot, one data, and one datashadowcopy.  If you need any more information I'd be happy to provide it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadow Copies are not "Backup", as in "everything gets copied on there".
You will only see shadow copy data when something is either modified or deleted from a folder.

So as long as no one in d:\share2 changes or deletes anything, the shadow copy stays empty.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks, the share that there are no copies of has all the users out this week, so that explains it.

Comment: @MichelZ Why do we have to setup the scheduler at all, if there will be made a shadow copy if something is modified or deleted? Should this not be made immediately after the change?